# Cron runs twice a day

Tags: uipath

I want to make a cron that runs at 9 a.m. and 6 p.m. every day, but I don't know how.

I looked for a way to create it, but I couldn't find one that runs twice a day at a specific time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru) to generate cron schedule expressions. In order to run a cron job twice a day at 9a.m and 6p.m, you should use `0 9,18 * * *`.